# How to convert NSData object with JPEG data into CVPixelBufferRef in OS X?

Tags: macos, cocoa, jpeg, avfoundation

As the title mentioned.

I search with Google and Stackoverflow, all resources are for UIImage converting, or convert NSImage FROM CVPixelBufferRef. Now what I want to do is convert JPEG raw data TO CVPixelBufferRef so that I could generate a movie file with live jpeg streams.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following method to convert from `NSImage` to `CVPixelBufferRef`:

```
- (CVPixelBufferRef)newPixelBufferFromNSImage:(NSImage*)image
{
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericRGB);
    NSDictionary* pixelBufferProperties = @{(id)kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey:@YES, (id)kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey:@YES};
    CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = NULL;
    CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, [image size].width, [image size].height, k32ARGBPixelFormat, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)pixelBufferProperties, &pixelBuffer);
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
    void* baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer);
    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer);
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, [image size].width, [image size].height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);
    NSGraphicsContext* imageContext = [NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithGraphicsPort:context flipped:NO];
    [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
    [NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext:imageContext];
    [image compositeToPoint:NSMakePoint(0.0, 0.0) operation:NSCompositeCopy];
    [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
    CFRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    return pixelBuffer;
}
```

The resulting buffer can be appended to an `AVAssetWriter` via `AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor`'s `appendPixelBuffer::`

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it on Monsday!

Comment: Thanks! I believe I may work! BTW, you mentioned about `appendPixelBuffer::`. Could you help me about [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17518173/presentationtime-parameter-of-the-avassetwriterinputpixelbufferadapter-append)? Thank you!