# Alamofire: Upload Jpg to a webservice in OSX

Tags: swift, macos, web-services, cocoa, alamofire

I am not sure if I am just misunderstanding the way Alamofire handles images but if I am uploading a JPG image to a webservice, its seems that it first requires me to convert it to a TIFF as NSData to upload.

Is there a way to preserve the original format when uploading via Swift in an OSX app?

```
let imageData = image.TIFFRepresentation
 Alamofire.upload(.POST, endpoint, multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData!, name: "file", fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alamofire doesn't care at all what the bytes in the data parameter are -- it uploads them as is.

You could just as easily do something like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17504245/3937

Note: this is not preserving the original format. An NSImage is uncompressed image data. And ... JPEG is lossy, so this will not be exactly what the image data is.

If you had an original JPEG (let's say in a file), you could create the NSData from that file instead and never create an NSImage object.

Comment: This is for Cocoa on OSX which doesn't have a UIImageJpegRepresentation

Comment: I read into this more- and I am still unclear. How would I then convert the Jpg file into one of the methods that is compatible with Alamofire?

Comment: I have managed to understand it more- basically it appears that its not possible to get the original fileurl from the imageview when you paste it into the imageview. There doesn't seem to be a call back so the only option is to convert it from NSImage.

Comment: You can't recover it from NSImage or the view, but you could keep it around when you first get it.

Comment: hmmm interesting idea Lou.  My app has 3 ways of uploading.  Drag and drop to Icon, upload button from readpanel and coping and pasting using keyboard/ mouse straight to imageview.  The first two - I can use your strategy but I don't think I can use that to intercept the paste so I might justs disable pasting